# How to implement C# REST calls like in PHP?

Tags: c#, rest, post

How to convert following REST calling method from PHP to C#? I'm new to C# and learning how to do web API calls.

When I run following C# code I get unauthorized error. But in PHP it's working fine.

PHP code:

```
$service_url = 'https://www.addresscope.com/api/v1/upas/get';

$ch = curl_init();
$auth = "Authorization: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
$curl_post_data = array( 'upas' => array("UPA000000")); 
$curl_post_data = http_build_query($curl_post_data); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array($auth)); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false);

$ch_result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)){  throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));  }
curl_close($ch);            

$curl_response = $ch_result;

$decoded = json_decode($curl_response); 
if (isset($decoded->status) && $decoded->status == 'error') 
{ 
  die('error occured: ' . $decoded->msg);     
} 
echo '<pre>';
echo 'response ok: '; var_dump($decoded);
```

C# code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System.Net.Http;

    .......
    .......
    .......

    var request =  
    (HttpWebRequest) 
    WebRequest.Create("https://www.addresscope.com/api/v1/upas/get");
    var postData = "upas=[UPA000000]";            
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    request.Headers["Authorization"] = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())            {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);            }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseString = new 
    StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    TextBox1.Text = responseString;
```

Comment: Try to add headers the correct way, request.Headers.Add("Authorization","xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"). By the way, you should not implicity calculate ContentLength, it's automatic.

Comment: Thanks for your tip @DvTr.. I changed headers as you said, but still getting following error {"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}

Comment: Some servers doesn't allow all content-types. As I can see, you're not specyfing any one in your PHP, but yes 'x-www-urlencoded-form' in your c#. By the way, in your PHP you specify to ignore server certificate (curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false);) but not in your c#. Perhaps the problem is that url got an invalid certificate, and then HttpWebRequest rejects to realize the connection.

Comment: Thanks for the insights @DvTr. That also could be the reason. Anyway, I found working code examples. And was able to make REST requests. Please check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the request after going through http://codesamplez.com/programming/http-request-c-sharp this post. 
I used this to prepare my class based on it. 
for the benefit of the reader I post what is needed to make REST request in C#.
Hope someone will find this useful.

```
        var request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.addresscope.com/api/v1/upas/get");
        Stream dataStream;
        WebResponse response;
        String Status;
        string responseFromServer;
        string postData = "upas[]=UPA000000";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);            
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx");            
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        request.Method = "POST";
        dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();            
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);            
        response = request.GetResponse();
        Status = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;            
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);            
        responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();            
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
        TextBox1.Text = responseFromServer;
```